# Infectiousness vs. deadliness for various diseases

Tags: data-request, medical, visualization, disease

I'm looking for a dataset of infectiousness vs. deadliness for various diseases and viruses.

I was inspired by this [visualization](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/ng-interactive/2014/oct/15/visualised-how-ebola-compares-to-other-infectious-diseases) from The Guardian.  I want to make some variations on this, but can't find the necessary data collected together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the data source for the figure from The Guardian

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHCEWY-d9HXlWrft9jjRQ2xf6WHQlmwyrXel6wjxkW8/edit?pli=1#gid=0

Lots of extra features in that data to look at.

Answer (score 5):

Both the US CDC and the World Health Organization have databases for statistics on infectious diseases. The entry points to the online databases are:

**CDC** http://wonder.cdc.gov/datasets.html

**WHO** http://apps.who.int/globalatlas/DataQuery/default.asp

http://who.int/research/en/

This is the EU Commission's portal on Communicable Diseases. I don't think you will find statistical data here, but lots of links to other resources:

**EU Commission** http://ec.europa.eu/health/communicable_diseases

Comment: Couldn't find anything at CDC.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a growing number of accredited and normalized ebola datasets at the [Africa Open Data](http://www.meetup.com/Africa-Open-Data/) [Ebola Data](http://eboladata.org) platform via [NuCivic](http://nucivic.com/).

(I work on the volunteer team developing this.)